# stop page to redirect when user press back key in webview android

Tags: android, webview

```
 public void onBackPressed (){
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
    if (webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();       
    }
    else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
    }
}
private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity.this);

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Processing");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }});
        progressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Processing");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }});
        progressDialog.show();
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

This is my code, i am loading a url in webview and showing a processing dialog when user redirect to another page, Now i want to stop my page to redirect and also hide processing dialog when user press the back key. I tried but not successful, Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: what behavior getting with current code

Comment: in my current code, its not doing anything, on click just redirect to another page, if i click on back button while redirecting nothing happens

Comment: means `onBackPressed` method executing or not?

Comment: yes its executing, but if i tried to make any change, my app crashed

Comment: :: `but if i tried to make any change, my app crashed ` what changes trying to make?

Comment: i was checking my processing dialog, if it is running and then printing something

Comment: i was checking if the loading is still running

Answer (score 0):

Clear history on finished page load.
No back history.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        mWebView.clearHistory();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
});
```